# How to specify registry while doing npm install with git remote url?

Tags: node.js, git-clone, npm-install

I want to be able to clone a git repository using a URL as specified [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> ```
> <protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish>]
> ```

I am getting an error saying

> npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/XYZ

So I should also be able to specify the registry while doing since modules are supposed to be picked up from  a internal repository.

Is it possible to **specify registry** while doing **npm install** with **git remote url**?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`npm` gets its config settings from the command line, environment variables, and npmrc files. You can try to specify registry in a npmrc file, and module in the command line. 
To change registry, you can use command:

```
npm config set registry <registry url>
```

You can also change configs with the help of `--` argument. Putting `--foo bar` on the command line sets the foo configuration parameter to "**bar**". So you can try something like that:

```
 npm install http://git.repo.url --registry=https://your.registry.local/
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried it. It doesn't work. Is there also a way of bypassing proxy in the same command?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Try to call  `npm config ls -l
` before running `npm install` with `--registry` argument, and seek `; userconfig /Users/username/.npmrc` line. Next line should be the registry option itself: `registry = "http://my-internal-registry.local/"`. Afterwards, call the command to install and change registry, and look to the configs once again. Registry option should be changed.

Comment: To bypass proxy, you should change `proxy` option in configs, and as I have already mentioned, you can do it with the help of `--` argument. It should look like: `npm intall module --proxy http://domain%5Cuser:pass@host:port`

Comment: `What do you mean by "doesn't work"?` It is not even recognizing the registry command with or without proxy. It simply checks in the global repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104528/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-gurvinder372).

Comment: This works but the syntax is actually: `--registry=https://your.registry.local/` You were missing the equals sign.

Comment: It seems that `npm install --registry http://customregistry.foo.bar.com` flag override does not seems to actually respect fully the registry address, but still tries connect to the npm default registry. Nor does the `--registry=http://customregistry.foo.bar.com`

Comment: The `--registry` argument is actually not working at all, see [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) or [yarn add](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Not the best way but If you are using mac or linux even in you can set alias for different registries.

```
##############NPM ALIASES######################
alias npm-default='npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org'
alias npm-sinopia='npm config set registry http://localhost:4873/'
```

Comment: The link with instructions for Windows is broken (actually as the Windows itself).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to use:

```
npm config set registry <registry url>.
```

to make sure you install your package from the registry inside your company.

If you are doing `npm -i -g`,  this is to install globally.

you need to do:

```
npm -g config set registry <registry url>
```

Comment: The above works with npm 6.x, for 8.x, it is npm config set <key>=<value> [<key>=<value> ...]; Refer: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config