# npm install "No compatible version found" for everything

Tags: npm

Upon executing the following command:

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.2.0' @angular/common@'^5.2.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.2.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.2.0' @angular/core@'^5.2.0' @angular/forms@'^5.2.0' @angular/http@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.2.0' @angular/router@'^5.2.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

I get messages saying that no compatible version of found for rxjs.  Then when I remove the specific version, it says no compatible version is found for angular/animations.  Then angular/common.  Etc etc.

I'm pretty sure these versions are valid, since they're the ones recommend by this Angular upgrade tool (https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) and I can also see the "valid install target" list, which includes the versions I'm trying to install.

I know our project's dependencies are in some special repository somewhere (Artifactory, I think?) so maybe this is happening because these versions are not in the repo NPM is looking at.

Is there a way to fix this for testing purposes before committing to having to install the new versions in the repo?  In other words, how do I point NPM at the NPM repo rather than the company's repo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer I was looking for was here:

[How to specify registry while doing npm install with git remote url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622933/how-to-specify-registry-while-doing-npm-install-with-git-remote-url)

However that didn't actually work.

The problem was simply a syntax issue.  After I removed all the quotes from my command so it looked like the following command, it worked

```
npm install @angular/animations@^5.2.0 @angular/common@^5.2.0 @angular/compiler@^5.2.0 @angular/compiler-cli@^5.2.0 @angular/core@^5.2.0 @angular/forms@^5.2.0 @angular/http@^5.2.0 @angular/platform-browser@^5.2.0 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^5.2.0 @angular/platform-server@^5.2.0 @angular/router@^5.2.0 typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@^5.5.2
```