# preventing npm from downloading over github

Tags: node.js, npm

this might be a weird question, but I am trying to install some npm packages in a restricted network.

All packages from npmjs.com works and downloads fine. Problem is that some of the dependencies have dependencies towards other packages that are downloaded through github.

And unfortunately github is blocked on my network, and there doesn't seem to be much I can do about it.

So my question is: Can one force npm to not go to github and try to resolve packages from npm instead?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need some sort of map that points from github to npm... Or maybe a proxy (?)

Comment: Check this  question out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622933/how-to-specify-registry-while-doing-npm-install-with-git-remote-url